# Adding a new security domain in JBoss 7.1.1Final

Tags: security, jsf, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I created a web application using JSF,EJB and JAAS with JBoss 7.1.1Final.
I am trying to add a security domain for login, so I edited the META-INF/jboss-web.xml like this:

```
<jboss-web>
 <context-root>A3App</context-root>
 <!-- Realm that will be used -->
 <security-domain>A3AppRealm</security-domain> // Also tried with java:/jaas/A3AppRealm
</jboss-web>
```

The security domain part of my standalone.xml looks like this: (I only added the first security domain and disabled other security domain)

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="A3AppRealm" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="CrudDSS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from users where email=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role, 'Roles' from users u where u.email=?"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Disabled" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
```

However, the exception I receive is:

> The security domain other has been disabled. All authentication will
>   fail. Please check your configuration to make sure this is expected.

I also tried with this configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.0">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="A3AppRealm" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="CrudDSS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from users where email=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role, 'Roles' from users u where u.email=?"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Disabled" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
```

The connection to the db works fine.
It seems not to use the security domain I have added.
Please help me solve it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by configuring my standalone.xml like this:

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/CrudDSS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from users where email=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role, 'Roles' from users u where u.email=?"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

And removing all the security domains,besides other, the login-module being under other security domain And also changed the jboss-web.xml like this:

```
 <security-domain>other</security-domain>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem only by removing the default's settings on security domain in standalone.xml

```
    <default-security-domain value="other"/>
```

I still have the other security domain.